# Creating a path from a 2d array of coords for AI to follow

Tags: java, arrays, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

Im making a simple tower defense game, I would like any wave of units I send to follow the path on the map, The path is made out of objects and wether that object is a path, tower or just grass is decided when the map is loaded from a text file.

I used this to fill a 2d array with the X and Y coords of every "path" object and space left over is set to 0.

My plan was to do this every time a new level loaded then work out which coords from the array were the corners from left of the screen to the right, this dont work well if the path loops back round and say the 7th corner of the path is now closer to te left of the screen then the 2nd corner so now im stuck.

My mind is now blank and any ideas would be of great help.

Comment: Sorry your question is not well defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had an idea, all my path objects are made when it reads in a "x" from the map text file so instead if i change all the corners in a map from "x" to say "1" and "2" and so on i can still make them path objects and at the same time add each corner from 1 to the end into the array in the right order and all left over space in the array can be set to the last corner!

Hope this helps anyone with the same kind of problem
I anwsered my own question :P but feel free to add anything